# MUX (multiplexer): Do all people follow the convention that the upper value is let through if sel is false?

Tags: multiplexer

[image]

**Do all people follow the convention that the upper value is let through if sel is false?**  (assuming the multiplexor is facing to the right as shown on the image)
I am asking this question because it doesn't seem like everyone follows this convention, which I thought was the case. Example ([from nand2tetris](https://www.coursera.org/learn/build-a-computer/lecture/XZhdS/unit-3-2-flip-flops)):
[image]

The upper value is let through the MUX when load is 1?!

Comment: Are you comparing a multiplexer to a register?

Comment: -1: There is no 'convention' other than "clearly label your input ports", this is not a question about electronics, but about an imagined pattern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because There is no 'convention' other than "clearly label your input ports", this is not a question about electronics, but about an imagined pattern. – DonFusili

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multiplexer is normally drawn with the inputs labeled with the select value(s) that enable them, so there's no confusion at all. Otherwise, there is no "convention".

If you find a schematic without such labels, like the one in your video, you have to hope that the functionality is obvious from context. In this case, the select line is labeled "load", so obviously, the upper input must be selected when it is active, because that's how you load a new input into the register.